# pthread_mutex_lock() only works when the return value is assigned to a variable, why?

Tags: c, pthreads, mutex

I'm trying to use mutex instead of semaphore because I want semaphore behavior but binary (not counting).  (Perhaps you'll notice I'm in the early stages of trying to simulate the Sleeping Barber algorithm.)  This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

int main( int argc, char** argv ) {

  int freeSeats = 6;

  pthread_mutexattr_t mutexAttr;
  pthread_mutex_t custWaiting, wrAccess, barberReady;

  pthread_mutexattr_setpshared(&mutexAttr, PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED);

  pthread_mutex_init(&custWaiting, &mutexAttr);
  pthread_mutex_init(&wrAccess, &mutexAttr);
  pthread_mutex_init(&barberReady, &mutexAttr);

  pthread_mutex_lock(&custWaiting);
  pthread_mutex_lock(&custWaiting);
  pthread_mutex_lock(&custWaiting);

  fprintf(stdout, "got here\n\n");

  return 0;

}
```

When I execute for the **first time**, this runs as expected (thread is blocked, command line hangs while my program waits to be able to lock).  When I kill the program, and run it a second time, it prints "got here", which it should not.  Why would this only fail on the second (and all following) attempts, but not on the first?

Bafflingly, if I modify the code as follows (only the init and lock lines):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

int main( int argc, char** argv ) {

  int freeSeats = 6;

  pthread_mutexattr_t mutexAttr;
  pthread_mutex_t custWaiting, wrAccess, barberReady;

  pthread_mutexattr_setpshared(&mutexAttr, PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED);

  int y = pthread_mutex_init(&custWaiting, &mutexAttr);
  y = pthread_mutex_init(&wrAccess, &mutexAttr);
  y = pthread_mutex_init(&barberReady, &mutexAttr);

  int x = pthread_mutex_lock(&custWaiting);
  x = pthread_mutex_lock(&custWaiting);
  x = pthread_mutex_lock(&custWaiting);

  fprintf(stdout, "got here\n\n");

  return 0;

}
```

... then it works every time.  The reason this is so maddening is because I can't check error codes on pthread_mutex_whatever() because it **doesn't** fail when I try to catch the error codes.  I don't want to assign the return values to `int`s if I'm not going to use them.  As you can see, I'm not using `x` or `y` at all; just assigning return values of `init` and `lock` functions to them.  So why does that change the behavior of the mutexes so drastically?  Or am I missing something else?  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should init your mutexattr by calling :

```
pthread_mutexattr_init(&mutexAttr);
```

And also set the type :

```
pthread_mutexattr_settype(amutexAttr, PTHREAD_MUTEX_NORMAL);
```

otherwise your code depends on the stack content, and the mutex can be of recursive type, which is why you see random behaviour. If you set the type to `PTHREAD_MUTEX_DEFAULT`, behaviour is undefined, while `PTHREAD_MUTEX_NORMAL` gives you deadlock

Comment: Thanks, great info.  I somehow missed in the docs that there was an init function for mutexattr (I looked for it but just didn't spot it).  I'll try that, and also try setting the type NORMAL.  Not sure why but for some reason I thought using pthread_mutex_setpshared(...) would cover the details that pthread_mutexattr_init(...) must cover.

Comment: This worked.  Great detailed answer.  Unfortunately revealed that mutex doesn't simulate a binary semaphore.

Answer (score 2):

You are taking the lock on the same mutex three times, this is undefined behavior unless you declare your mutex to be recursive. Probably you meant to lock the three different mutexes.

The undefined behavior means that anything can happen, including the behavior that you observe, here.

To set the properties of a mutex, you'd have to change the properties of the mutex attribute with `pthread_mutexattr_settype`. There are basically two types that augment the default behavior, `PTHREAD_MUTEX_ERRORCHECK` and `PTHREAD_MUTEX_RECURSIVE`. The first would block if you try to re-lock, the second can be used to lock and unlock multiple times.

The default behavior is leaving this undefined, because implementing such checks are costly.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful info but also raises more questions for me.  To clarify, I was locking the same mutex multiple times intentionally.  I wanted to force deadlock as a test that it was working.  I didn't know that would be undefined behavior.  I suppose I don't understand why a mutex would be useful if a process trying to lock an already-locked mutex would result in undefined behavior (instead of just process blocking).  Is my confusion understandable?